# Why is my pruned git repo still so big, or, why is there so much pushing for git push --tags?

Tags: git

I ran:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter cannery/assemblies master
```

to turn a clone of a big repo into a much smaller repo.

But when I push --tags with the results, it seems rather large:

```
Counting objects: 36747, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13463/13463), done.
Writing objects: 100% (36713/36713), 65.47 MiB | 1.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 36713 (delta 14866), reused 36676 (delta 14854)
```

This is really small collection of stuff in cannery/assemblies.

Have I somehow retained a raft of things I don't want? How could I find out?

Comment: Most of the tutorials on using `git filter-branch` go on to discuss emptying your reflogs and then repacking and pruning your repository to remove stuff that is no longer referenced by any branch heads, but may still be referenced by your reflogs. If you haven't done those steps, the things you removed will eventually age out and disappear, but the default age threshholds are a bit long if you're looking for an immediate size reduction...

Comment: Maybe also see the description of --tag-name-filter in the documentation?  I guess tags aren't updated automatically (I certainly wouldn't expect them to be).

Answer (score 0):

Your commits are orphan. However, it will take some time for them to be garbage-collected and reduce the size of the repo.

If you want to force it run:

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Comment: Try ``git clone`` to create a pristine new repo.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful person at github provided the diagnosis.

This started as a pretty big svn repo. It passed through svn2git. As of this point, the svn 'tags' referenced appropriate subsets of the entire repo.

Then I stupidly ran the maven-release-plugin in git for the small part of the big repo that I later set out to split into its own repo. This created a tag that referenced the whole repo.

So, then when I filtered, that reference kept the whole shooting match alive.

The repair was to delete this tag and then re-gc.